# sorting arrays with increasing order

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort my array with ascending order, I prompted  the user to enter 5 numbers then I stored them in the array `numberList`.

After I want to display the array in ascending order. I tried using `Arrays.sort(numberList)` and that did not work. There's an error right under the word sort

How can I sort it?!

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Arrays;
        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class Array {

            public static void main (String[] args) {

                ArrayList<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Enter number 1");
                numberList.add(input.nextInt());

                System.out.println("Enter number 2");
                numberList.add(input.nextInt());

                System.out.println("Enter number 3");
                numberList.add(input.nextInt());

                System.out.println("Enter number 4");
                numberList.add(input.nextInt());

                System.out.println("Enter number 5");
                numberList.add(input.nextInt());

                    System.out.println(numberList);
                    for(int i = numberList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--);

                    System.out.println("The list in ascending order:");
                    System.out.println(Arrays.sort(numberList));
                }
            }
```

Comment: ...and what error would that be?

Comment: There's an error under the word sort (ex: Arrays.sort(numberList);)

Comment: Also, why are you attempting to sort multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.sort(numberList));
```

To:

```
   Collections.sort(numberList);
   System.out.println(numberList);
```

Because the method `Arrays.sort(...)` is applicable for the arguments `ArrayList<Integer>.`
For that use `Collections.sort(...)`

Answer (score 0):

you want to sort the ArrayList. To sort the ArrayList we have to use **Collections.sort(numberList)** method. **Arrays.sort(numberList)** method is to sort the array not the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Arrays.sort for an int array and making i >= 0 will make your loop count in descending order and add 0 to the end of the loop. Instead try something like this:

```
                System.out.println(numberList);
                for(int i = numberList.size(); i > 0; i--){

                System.out.println("The list in ascending order:");
                System.out.println(i);
```